# Fullcalendar: Events with open and closed day background/marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I was building a Calendar with dynamic events.

Simplest representation of my event object 

`id : " sdsddsd "
start : "2018-05-13T0..."
end : "2018-05-26T0"
open_monday: true
open_tuesday: false
open_wednesday: true
open_thursday: false
...`


So in the month view calendar, I wanted to show my events and within the event if `open_monday` is true then set the background of that day grid to green. The following Tuesday will use the value `open_tuesday` and it is false so it will display red.

The red and green background will only be inside an Event. If the day grid isn't within any event, it will be left as blank.

How can I do this. Or is there a better way to do this using `resources`, `constraints`etc. ?.

Thanks.

Comment: Those settings are relative to the calendar, so you shouldn't set it from event attributes..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand, but it is rather strange to pass the whole list of open/closed weekdays with each event. You should rather determine which weekday your event is and act accordingly. Just add an eventRender callback field to your calendar to control exactly the layout of the HTML element rendering the event. See
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

To know the weekday of an event, use

```
moment(event.start).day()
```

See
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

Alternatively, you can add an eventDataTransform field to your calendar, which will be applied to each event when it is loaded, so you can change any of its layout specifiers (color, backgroundColor, className...), see list at
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks for reply. 
The event object only holds the moment object for start and end. I want to know the days within the days